How would you calculate the electron density in a crystal, given the wave functions of the energy bands at a given $r$ and $k$?
I am using the empirical pseudopotential method (EPM) to investigate the properties of Silicon and other semiconductors. By finding the eigenvectors of the matrix in the EPM I am able to find the wave functions of each energy band, for a given $r$ and $k$.
I would like to extend my program to be able to plot the electron density in a plane of the crystal. Is it possible to calculate the electron density in the crystal using the wave functions of each energy band.
